# How to convert lowercase characters of a string to uppercase characters in C++?

Tags: c++, string, class, output, uppercase

I have a question where all lowercase characters of a string should be converted into uppercase characters.But as per the question, certain lines in the code should not be changed. I have written the code below.

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <string>
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <ctype.h>
 using namespace std;

 class StringOps {
 public:
   void stringToUpper(string &s) //This line should not be changed
  {
    char c;
    int i=0;
    while (s[i])
    {
     c=s[i];
     putchar (toupper(c));
     i++;
    }
  }
 };

 int main(void)
 {
   string str ="Hello World";  
   StringOps obj;
   obj.stringToUpper(str);
   cout << str;            //This line should not be changed
   return 0;
   }
```

I get the output as:

```
HELLO WORLDHello World
```

But the required output is:

```
HELLO WORLD HELLO WORLD
```

How do I make the

```
 cout<<str;
```

statement in main() to print the result computed in the function :

```
 void stringToUpper(string &s)
```

Comment: Well, it looks like you want to modify `s` in `stringToUpper`, rather than just read from it.

Comment: You should seek to make `stringToUpper` _change_ `s` instead of printing something like it is currently doing.

Comment: Thank you!! I understood my mistake now.

Answer (score 0):

Solution only for the lower part of ASCII characters.

```
class StringOps {
public:
  void stringToUpper(string& s) //This line should not be changed
  {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < s.size(); ++i) {
      if (s[i] > 96 && s[i] < 123)
        s[i] -= 32;
    }
  }
};
```

and if you care about the higher part of the ASCII table:

```
class StringOps {
public:
  void stringToUpper(string& s) //This line should not be changed
  {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < s.size(); ++i) {
      s[i] = toupper(s[i]);
    }
  }
};
```

If you have some multi-byte encoding, like UTF-8, you will need some library.

Comment: Thank you for your effort!!

Answer (score 0):

> cout << str;            //This line should not be changed

This means that you must change `str`.

> void stringToUpper(string &s) //This line should not be changed

Good news, your method take `s` as a reference.

In your code you are doing `c=s[i];` you should reassign the char in your string `s[i] = c`

Answer (score 0):

You are just printing the string with making each character as upper character, but the string that passed to function (by reference) "s" does not get changed.

```
void stringToUpper(string &s)
```

A line can be added to make s to get changed in void stringToUpper(string &s)

```
 s[i] = toupper(c);
```

Code will look

```
 c=s[i];
 s[i] = toupper(c);
 putchar (toupper(c));
 i++;
```

Output will be

```
HELLO WORLDHELLO WORLD
```